# Display data from object in Strapi

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3, strapi

When I write `{{ posts }}` I see this object but when I want to display it in a `v-for`, it doesn't show up.

This is what I have by using `{{ posts }}`

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Post numer jeden",
        "content": "tresc w poscie numer jeden",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-27T17:51:40.396Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-27T17:51:44.406Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-10-27T17:51:44.405Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Post numer dwa",
        "content": "Tresc w poscie numer dwa",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-27T17:52:06.344Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-27T17:52:07.669Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-10-27T17:52:07.668Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 2
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ posts }}</p>
  <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post">
    <hr />
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p>dsdsa</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
    this.posts = res.data;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try `posts.data` instead of `posts` in your v-for loop. That is the array with the posts. Or set posts to `res.data.data`. For the title you should use `post.attributes.title`.

Comment: @Gabe I've posted an answer but you were the first one, feel free to post yours (I'll delete mine in that case).

Comment: I've edit your question to make it into something more readable. Please make an effort next time, regarding the formatting.

Comment: No worries, @kissu, that’s fine

Answer (score 1):

This is a [common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937529/8816585), solved by going one level down.

Try the following

```html
<div v-for="post in posts.data" :key="post.id">
```